# dBNull.value and is operator

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio-2008, operator-keyword, dbnull

I am porting a VB2005 web app to VB2008, and running into problems compiling it.

The problem is caused when I try to compile the project, I get this error on the line:

`If m Is DBNull.Value...`

Error:

```
'Is' operator does not accept operands of type 'Integer'. 
Operands must be reference or nullable types.
```

Code:

```
Public Shared Function getNextID(ByVal t As String, ByVal f As String)

        Dim m = 0

        Dim c As New Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection
        c = getConn()
        c.Open()

        Dim s As String
        s = "SELECT MAX(" & f  & ")AS max FROM " & t

      Dim q As New Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand(s, c)
        Dim r = q.EmecuteReader

        While r.Read
            m = r.GetValue(0)
        End While

        If m Is DBNull.Value Then
            m = 1
        Else
            m += 1
        End If

        r = Nothing
        q = Nothing
        c.Close()
        c = Nothing

        Return m

End Function
```

Is there a way  to allow this fucntion to operate without changing it? And if not, how would I fix it?

Answer (score 3):

Your problem is the following line:

```
Dim m = 0
```

I suspect that the reason it worked in VS2005 is because `Option Strict` was turned off, so the type of `m` defaulted to `Object`.  In other words, in VS2005, with `Option Strict Off`, the above line would be the equivalent of:

```
Dim m As Object = 0
```

If `m` is an object, then any value referenced by it would be *boxed*, so the `Is` operation would be allowed.  In your VS2008 project, however, I suspect that `Option Infer` is turned on (a feature that did not exist in 2005), so the type of `m` is inferred at compile-time to be an `Integer` because you set it equal to an integer literal (`Dim m = 0`).  In other words, in VS2008, with `Option Infer On` the above line would be the equivalent of:

```
Dim m As Integer = 0
```

Since it is declared as an `Integer` type, rather than an `Object` type, you can't us the `Is` operator anymore.  More information about this can be found on [this page](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/zcd4xwzs.aspx) of the MSDN, where this example is given:

> Dim qty = 5
>
> - If Option Infer is on (the default), the variable takes the data type of the initializer. See Local Type Inference (Visual Basic).
> - If Option Infer is off and Option Strict is off, the variable takes the data type of Object.
> - If Option Infer is off and Option Strict is on, a compile-time error occurs.

The easiest way to fix the problem would be to simply turn `Option Infer Off` so that it will compile in the same way as VS2005.  If, however, you want to leave `Option Infer On` and, instead, fix the code, you'll need to specify the variable type, like this:

```
Dim x As Object = 0
```

You might think you can fix it by changing the way you check if `m Is DBNull`.  For instance, either of the following lines would compile:

```
If Convert.IsDBNull(m) Then
```

Or:

```
If TypeOf m Is DBNull Then
```

However, you'll notice that neither of those two `If` statements will ever evaluate to true. If `m` is declared as an `Integer`, then it can never be `DBNull`.  If the column in the database ever equalled null, the following line would throw an exception because it would try to cast a `DbNull` object to an `Integer` which is impossible:

```
m = r.GetValue(0) ' This will throw exception if column is null and m is an integer
```

The only way for the `m` variable to support equaling either an `Integer` or a `DbNull` object is if it were declared as `Object`.

If the project has many places where no type is specified, like this, you should turn off `Option Infer`.  If you want to find all of the places where it is a problem, so that you can fix them all in the code, and then turn `Option Infer` back on, you can temporarily turn `Option Infer Off` and turn `Option Strict On`.  When `Option Strict` is on and `Option Infer` is off, the project will not compile unless all variable types are always specified.

Answer (score 0):

You could eliminate the problem at the database query stage with something like

```
SELECT COALESCE(MAX(" & f & "), 0) AS max FROM " & t
```

and then unconditionally increment m.

Also, you could use ExecuteScalar instead of ExecuteReader, seeing as you are only getting one value.

Answer (score 0):

Just make your variable m nullabale

```
  Dim m As Nullable(Of  Integer)
```